# Resizing text in uitableviewcell

Tags: iphone, ipad

I have a label in the table view cell whose size i have to resize depending on the text in the label. In potratit mode it works fone, but when shifted to landscape mode the text is not displayed to the length of the table cell.  For the time being i have created the label dynamically and adjusted its width depending on the current orientation of the device by reloading the table.

I have created the lable dynamically and also added it on the contentView. The code is as follows

```
UILabel *lblSize = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(nameLbl.frame.origin.x + nameLbl.frame.size.width , 0, 580, 60)];
lblSize.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
lblSize.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"TrebuchetMS" size:18];
lblSize.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
lblSize.minimumFontSize = 10;
lblSize.tag = 3;
[cell.contentView addSubview:lblSize];
```

What happens when i execute the code in portrait mode is below

|Page1  | Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text.... |

What happens in landscape mode is below

|Page 1 | Some text. Some text. ....                                |

I do not want to use the approach that i have used. Is there something else and more appropriate that can be used to solve the problem. Please do suggest some solution. I am currently working with iPad and need a solution for the same.

Comment: Are you facing problem in setting height of label?

Comment: See my answer below. You need to resize label by checking how much size it's text should take with current font size.

Answer (score 0):

just set the frame with this bellow condition

```
    if (UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape([UIDevice currentDevice].orientation))
    {
         // code for landscape orientation      
    }
```

or

```
    if (UIDeviceOrientationIsPortrait([UIDevice currentDevice].orientation))
    {
         // code for Portrait orientation       
    }
```

Comment: I have already done that what you are suggesting and it works fine. But i dont want to use that as i have to call table reload on every rotation which i dont want to do. So i'm searching for some other work around

Comment: then what you want exactly dude??

Comment: I have set the label width to a fixed value which works fine in portrait mode. But when in landscape mode, the view width increases and also the cell width but the text within the cell takes only the fixed width of the label. So without changing the width i want that the text in the label should occupy the entire cell width irrespective of any mode.

Comment: then set the text as a cell textLable like ..             cell.textLabel.text = yourText; try this mate but if you set UILable then here you must change the width of lable mate and for this you must call the method [table reloadData]; so try this mate..

Answer (score 0):

Use following in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

```
CGFloat maxHeightForLabel=1000.0;
CGSize size=[label.text sizeWithFont:label.font
       constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(label.frame.size.width, maxHeightForLabel)];
CGRect frame=label.frame;
frame.size=size;
label.frame=frame;
```

Call `[yourTableView reloadData];` on orientation change.